# Restore activity with the right fragment and state

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I have an application with a main menu that when clicked, navigate to different activities.

One of these activities its a Search, with container that i update with many fragments. Its a kind of search, with 3 steps. (Step 1, Step 2, Step 3)

When i go for other activity and back to the Search Activity, the state is lost.

Whats is the best way to restore the activity with the right fragment ?

I have tried **android:launchMode="singleInstance"**  and also **intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)** to force one instance of activity, and actually works but is taking time to open the activity for the first time (the app kind of stop works and then start again)

I think i can't just use savedInstanceState() because, each fragment need some information chosen on the previous fragment

Any suggestion ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!--Top bar Menu-->
    <include  layout="@layout/partials_top_bar"/>


    <FrameLayout
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </FrameLayout>


    <!--Bottom Bar Menu-->
    <include  layout="@layout/partials_bottom_bar"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

When the user choose some action, them i update the actual fragment with

```
        activity.supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit()
```

**EDIT: Found a solution. The "delay" / App freeze showed when i open SingleInstance was caused by removing the transition animation of all activities. But only the single instance activity presents this delay. So i'm gonna use this. Thank you so much guys.**

Comment: can you show where you are adding fragemnt in your activity

Comment: I included some code, it helps ?

Comment: The first fragment is added in the Framelayout in OnCreate? can you post oncreate code?

Comment: Yes, i add in onCreate function, the code is the same but i use .add( ) instead of .replace()

Comment: Try and wrap that code(where first fragment is added) inside if(savedInstance == null) and then try.

Comment: For some reason the savedInstance is always null when i click to open the activity again, except when i use launchMode="singleInstance" ... what makes the activity have that delay ...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static variable "state" in your activity, could be String, and when you change Fragment, you change de variable value, for example, when you change to the StepOneFragment you put the value to 
"step_one", StepTwoFragment -> "step_two", StepThreeFragment -> "step_three", and if you get back you change the variable value depending in what fragment are you on, then in onCreate of SearchActivity, you make a switch in that variable, and depending of the value, you load the desired Fragment.

Hope it helps

Comment: Im trying to implement this, but the onCreated (), method is always called with savedInstance==null, when i click to open the same activity again...  
Except when i use launchMode="singleInstance" , 

But onSaveInstanceState() is always called when i change activity